# How can I echo an image in a PHP script?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a small problem. I have made a small database for storing found geocaches. When someone submits a geocache, and it successfully goes into the database, I want an image to appear. This is a snip of the code that I have right now. All it does is say, "Thank you for submitting your geocache!"

```
if(!$query)
    echo mysql_error();
else {
    echo "<h1>Thank you for logging your geocache!</h1>";
}
```

This returns fine, but if i use THIS code:

```
if(!$query)
    echo mysql_error();
else {
    echo "<img src="checkmark.png">";
}
```

This code will return a 500 server error.

So, the big question, how do I echo an image in this script?

Comment: do you want to echo the image or the image tag? there are two completely different things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using unescaped double quotes around checkmark.png which terminates the echo statement early, causing it to be invalid. Try `"<img src='checkmark.png'>";` or `"<img src=\"checkmark.png\">";` instead.

Comment: Or better yet, `'<img src="checkmark.png">';`, which avoids unnecessary parsing of the string for variable expansion.

Comment: @please, not this old and nasty rumor.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Using apostrophes instead of quotes worked.